# Composer: Invalid version constraint/string "/Program"

Tags: php, composer-php, laravel-5

I've been trying to install `kirkbushell/eloquence` (using `composer require kirkbushell/eloquence ~1.2`) for my Laravel 5 project, but I get the following error:

```
[UnexpectedValueException]
Could not parse version constraint /Program: Invalid version string "/Program"
```

Thing is, I'm not sure where to find the file that's using `/Program` as a version.

I'm running the latest Composer (as of writing this) on Windows 8.1.

What could be causing this, and how do I resolve it?

Comment: Any reason you are not using Homestead? You'll avoid all sorts of strange errors (possibly like this one) by using it when running on a windows machine.

Comment: Well I've never had issues before - not a single one. Also, I prefer to run my apps directly on Windows.

Comment: What are your production environments? Windows IIS or Linux?

Comment: I'm running the usual Apache setup (on Windows).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it. Should be using:

```
composer require kirkbushell/eloquence:~1.2
```

instead of

```
composer require kirkbushell/eloquence ~1.2
```

Otherwise, `~` is being expanded. The use of the colon prevents this.